# How to set NSAttributedString range?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

A little confused with using the syntax. 
I know you are supposed to use NSFontAttributeName, however I don't know how to correctly specify the range.

I'm curious about two cases.

How do I specify the range for all characters in the text, and how do I specify the range as something like the first 10 characters.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Don't use magic numbers

```
let baseString = "Don't use magic numbers."

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: baseString, attributes: nil)

let dontRange = (attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: "Don't")
attributedString.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)], range: dontRange)
```

So meta

Comment: The string I'm using is coming from user input... I'm using a UITextView how you'd use a UITextField

Comment: So I need a range to represent all characters in the string

Comment: @stefan if you want to affect the whole string just pass them where I passed the nil

Comment: thanks a lot , but how would I do if I want set the attribute by a dic?

Answer (score 6):

In XCode 10 and swift 4 I used this way:

```
let customizedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "My Text")
customizedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strokeWidth, value: 5.0, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: customizedText.string.count))
customizedText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.strokeColor, value: #colorLiteral(red: 0.5725490451, green: 0, blue: 0.2313725501, alpha: 1), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: customizedText.string.count))
myLabel.attributedText = customizedText
```